# Why cant I cast a void* back to an int* and dereference it?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Im trying to understand threading in C from a lab from my teacher and this is the way he had us do it in class.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define numberlen 1000000
int sum = 0;
int arr[numberlen];


void* Summing(void* param)
{
    int n = *((int*)param); //I'm guessing this is where my issue is but I'm still a first year so i'm not sure.
    int base = 500000 * n;
    for(int i =0; i<500000;i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i+base];
    }
}




int main()
{
    int nonthreadsum = 0;
    pthread_t thread_id_first;
    pthread_t thread_id_second;
    


    srand(time(NULL)); 
    
    for(int i = 0; i<numberlen;i++)
    {
        int r = (rand() % 10);
        arr[i] = r;
        nonthreadsum += r;
    }
    printf("%d\n",nonthreadsum);

    pthread_create(&thread_id_first, NULL, Summing, (void*)0);
    pthread_create(&thread_id_second, NULL, Summing, (void*)1);

    
    printf("%d\n", sum);


    return 1;
}
```

The issue I keep running into is that pthread functions only allow void*'s as arguments to pass to the actual function to be run. Otherwise I'd just put 0 or 1 in as the argument. If anyone knows a way around this i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pass the Address of Your Data to Your Thread

Pass the address of your data to a thread. Do not pass your data inside a pointer.

The intended way to pass data to a thread is to pass a pointer to it. For example, to pass data whose type is `Type`, you can use:

```
Type x;
// … Set desired value(s) in x.
pthread_create(&thread_id_first, NULL, Summing, &x);
```

You can pass `(void *) &x` but do not need to. The conversion to `void *` will be automatic in C, for a parameter declared as type `void *`.

Then, in the thread, you should restore the pointer type:

```
void *Summing(void *param)
{
    Type *p = param;
    Type x = *p;
    // … Use x.
}
```

The conversion of the pointer from `void *` (`Type *p = param;`) and the use of the pointer (`Type x = *p;`) are shown in two lines above for illustration. However, you can combine them into one line: `Type x = * (Type *) param;`.

### Why `void *` Is Used

Any kind of data can be passed to a thread, via an address. However, C does not have good provisions for passing any kind of pointer to a routine. `pthread_create` must be declared with a specific pointer type. `void *` is used to serve as a generic type of pointer. So `pthread_create` has a `void *` parameter, but you can pass it any type of pointer to an object.

In your case, the type can be an `int`, replacing `Type` in the sample code above. Given `int x;`, `&x` will be a pointer to an `int`, `int *`. When you pass it to `pthread_create`, it will be automatically converted to `void *`.

Then, in the thread, you need to convert it back to an `int *`. After you do that, you can access the `int` that it points to.

### Passing Lots of Data

Threads are often passed more data than just a simple `int`. The `Type` can be an object type. Often, a structure is used. A program will define a structure, such as:

```
struct foo
{
    int start;
    int end;
    double coefficient;
    double ReferenceData[30];
}
```

As with the `Type` example, one would create an object of the desired type, `struct foo x;`, fill it with data, and pass `&x` to `pthread_create`. Then the thread will convert the `void *` it receives to `struct foo *` and use it to access the data.

In this case, because there is so much data, the thread might not want to copy it, which is what `struct foo x = * (struct foo *) param;` does. Instead, the thread might just make a pointer of the right type, `struct foo *p = param;`. Then the thread can use the data through the `->` operator: `p->start`, `p->ReferenceData[i]`, and so on.

Threads can also pass results back to their creators this way, by putting results in the pointed-to-data.

### Passing Just a Little Data

To pass a small amount of data, there is a shortcut: You can create an object and pass its address using a compound literal:

```
pthread_create(&thread_id_first, NULL, Summing, & (int) {1});`.
```

This creates an `int` object with the value 1 and passes its address to `pthread_create`. Then the thread would get the `int` with `int x = * (int *) param;`.

Generally, the code construction `(type) {initial values}` is called a compound literal. It creates an object with type *type* and the given initial values. The `&` takes its address.

Compound literals have automatic storage duration, so the `& (int) {1}` will exist (have memory reserved for it) only until the end of the execution of the routine that creates it. You should not let that routine end until the thread is done using the compound literal.

If you need an object to persist longer than execution of the routine that will create the thread, you can use `malloc` to reserve memory for the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's allowed (in some cases) to cast from an integer to a pointer and from a pointer to an integer.  The problem is that's not what you're attempting to do.

When you call `pthread_create`, you're casting the integer values `1` and `0` to type `void *`.  This is fine.  But then in the thread function you do this:

```
int n = *((int*)param);
```

You cast the `void *` argument to `int *` and then attempt to dereference that pointer.  But you didn't pass in an `int *`.  You passed an `int`.  So your program is treating the values 1 and 0 as pointers (the latter of which is actually a NULL pointer).

Since you converted from `int` to `void *` when you passed the values to the function, you want to cast back to `int` inside of the function.

```
int n = (int)param;
```

That being said, the best way to handle this would be to pass an actual `int *` to the function and convert it back in the function.  Converting from an `int *` to a `void *` and back *is* well defined in all cases.

You can do this by defining variables in the `main` function to dynamically create memory to hold these values:

```
int *t1_val = malloc(sizeof(*t1_val));
int *t2_val = malloc(sizeof(*t2_val));
*t1_val = 0;
*t2_val = 1;
pthread_create(&thread_id_first, NULL, Summing, t1_val);
pthread_create(&thread_id_second, NULL, Summing, t2_val);
```

Then using them in the thread as you were, adding a call to `free`:

```
int n = *((int*)param);
free(param);
```

You could also do this without dynamic allocation by using variables of type `int` and passing their address, but you would need to make sure those variables don't go out of scope by the time the thread attempts to dereference the pointer.

Comment: Sorry I actually tried this and got a compilation error `Threads.c:13:14: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   13 |     int n = ((int)param);
      |`

Comment: @AlexanderCrowe That's actually a warning (not an error) which in this case is fine because you know the original type of the value.  There are situations where such a conversion could result in truncation but not in this case.

Comment: @AlexanderCrowe You can silence this warning with an additional cast to `intptr_t`, i.e. `int n = (int)(intptr_t)param;`

Comment: Converting an integer to a pointer and back is not guaranteed to work as desired. The intended way to use the `void *` parameter is to pass a pointer to data (such as a structure) and for the thread to convert the `void  *` back to the same type. Teaching the use of a pointer to smuggle an integer is a bad answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, notwithstanding the advisability of the technique, it is what *the OP's instructor* is teaching, and what the OP must deal with.  Explaining how to deal with it is exactly what an answer to the question posed must do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Nowhere in the question does it state what the OP’s instructor is teaching. At the top, it says “this is the way he had us do it in class.” In the code below, there are two relevant places. In the first, `*(int*)param` is a correct way to use an `int` passed by reference through a `void *`. In the second, `(void*)1` is a bad way to smuggle an integer in a `void *`. Figuring the second is what the teacher taught is an assumption made by you and dbush, without any apparent basis. Surely it is more likely the teacher taught the good way, and the second way is the student’s error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Added instructions on how to use pointers properly.